# Bash complex pipeline dependencies

Tags: linux, bash, concurrency, parallel-processing, pipeline

I'm trying to model a build concurrent pipeline in a single Bash script.  I know I can use other tools, but at this point I'm doing it out of understanding Bash.
[image: Here's a diagram of the task flow that I'm trying to model in Bash.]

Scheduling jobs parallel is easy, and waiting for them all at the end is easy.  But I want to make it run faster by trigger Task A.2 immediately after Task A.1 & Task X.  To make it even hard on myself, the code in Task A.1 & Task A.2 is related & sequential, so it would be nice if I could keep the code sequential as well.

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

{
    echo "Task X"
} &
DEPENDENCY=$!

{
    echo "Task A.1"
    wait "${DEPENDENCY}"
    echo "Task A.2"
} &

{
    echo "Task B.1"
    wait "${DEPENDENCY}"
    echo "Task B.2"
} &

wait
```

This is ideally what I want, but it doesn't work because child processes can't wait for each other--which makes sense--but I'm hoping I can make this work in a cross platform way.

I actually have this working, but but I wasn't able to keep the code for part *.1 and *.2

Also it would be nice if this can work for OSX & Linux.  I'm hoping a Bash expert can chime in and show a succinct way of expressing this in Bash.

Comment: This is a perfect job for Make.

Comment: yes https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Parallel.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to make this work for OSX & Linux is to use namedpipes to signal to batch jobs that they can continue.  Unfortunately it requires splitting up "Task *.1" & "Task *.2", but it's the best I can come up with for the moment.

```
#!/bin/bash

function cleanup {
  rm -f .task.a.1.done .task.b.1.done
}
trap cleanup EXIT
cleanup

mkfifo .task.a.1.done
mkfifo .task.b.1.done

{
    echo "Task A.1"
    echo -n "" > .task.a.1.done
} &

{
    echo "Task B.1"
    echo -n "" > .task.b.1.done
} &

{
    echo "Task X"
}

{
    cat < .task.a.1.done
    echo "Task A.2"
} &

{
    cat < .task.b.1.done
    echo "Task B.2"
} &

wait
```

Answer (score 7):

As the comments to the question point out, the following Makefile is equivalent to your shell script (but doesn’t touch the file system)

```
.PHONY: a1 a2 b1 b2 x

all: a2 b2 

a1:
    @echo "Task A.1"

b1:
    @echo "Task B.1"

x:
    @sleep 1.5; echo "Task X"

a2: a1 x
    @echo "Task A.2"

b2: b1 x
    @echo "Task B.2"
```

Try it with `make -j5` to allow for five parallel threads. It requires GNU make, which is available for every platform in existence, even if it might not be distributed by default. The initial `.PHONY:` target ensures that all tasks are executed even if files named `a1`, `a2`, ... happen to exist.

Comment: I wouldn't have thought of using Make to orchestrate tasks, that is a GREAT idea, I will have to remember it :)