# GNU Parallel: how to prevent specific jobs from being processed in parallel

Tags: bash, parallel-processing, gnu-parallel

**GIVEN**:

A set of jobs to be run in parallel: { `app0`, `app1`, `app2`, .... }

**QUESTION**:

How is it possible to initiate the tool 'GNU parallel' to run all jobs in parallel, whereby some specific jobs prevented from running concurrently?

**EXAMPLE**:

If `appX` and `appY` rely on the same resources, how can one specify that  `appX` may run in parallel with `app0`, `app1`, ... but never with `appY`?

**EXAMPLE 2**:

`appX` and `appY` may run in parallel, but neither of them shall be running concurrently with `appZ`.

Comment: If the rules are not too complicated, remove `appX` and `appY` from the list and replace with `appZ = { appX ; appY; }`

Comment: Not a solution for GNU parallel, but somewhat related and interesting to read: [Bash complex pipeline dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48834884/6770384)

Comment: If Mark Setchell's solution is not an option because you want non-deterministic behavior allowing for `appX; ...; appY` as well as `appY; ...; appX` then you can use locking mechanisms in `appX` and `appY`, see [ensure only one instance of a shell script is running at a time](https://stackoverflow.com/q/185451/6770384).

Comment: @MarkSetchell: I like the elegance of your solution. Could you make this an answer, so I could mark it as response? However, your solution seems a little intrusive with respect to the time sequencing. GNU parallel could not choose to run `appX` wait some time and then run `appY`.

Comment: Let's rather wait till Ole Tange, the author of GNU Parallel, logs in. He always has great ideas for applying `parallel` to problems.

Comment: If the processes are not dependent on each other, need to be run sequentially however in any order, you should just implement a lock between them. I can blindly tell, they need to share some resource. The access to this resource should be protected by a lock.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not 100% clear to me what you want. Maybe replace appX and appY with:

```
sem --id myidXY --fg appX
sem --id myidXY --fg appY
```

Which can be done like this:

```
... | parallel eval '{= s/(app(X|Y))/sem --id appXY --fg $1/ =}'
```

This should make sure only a single `appX` or `appY` is running; but let plenty of `appZ`s running.

`{= =}` is interpreted as Perl code.

`s/(app(X|Y))/sem --id appXY --fg $1/` replaces `appX` or `appY` with `sem --id appXY --fg` followed by either `appX` or `appY` depending in what was matched. If nothing is matched then the value is unchanged.

```
(echo appX; echo appX; echo appX; 
 echo appY; echo appX; echo appV;
 echo appX; echo appZ) |
  parallel eval '{= s/(app(X|Y))/sem --id appXY $1/ =}'
```

If that is not what you mean, please edit the question.

Comment: Yes, the semaphore seems to be the solution. Could you, please, elaborate on the '{= ... =}' construct? How would the complete command line look, if there were, for example three more apps, A, B, and C?

Comment: Nice solution! Quick question though, if appX is running, and it goes to start appY that will block and thereby hog a job-slot until appX finishes - won't it?

Comment: Yes, there is a risk that all but one jobslots is waiting for the one.